# Regular expression needed to replace token and transform into a FontAwesome <i> tag

Tags: regex, font-awesome, quill

I'm looking for a regular expression to search a string for anything between the two colons, and transform it into a FontAwesome `<i>` tag.

What is between the `::token::` is what is **exactly** what inserted in the `<i>` FontAwesome tag

It will need to replace all of the  `::tokens::` in a string as the string may contain many tokens.

> Examples

Replace:

```
::fa-camera-retro::
```

with

```
<i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

and others like:

```
::fb::
```

with

```
<i class="fas fb"></i>
```

**Note:**
I'm  using this as a way to insert FontAwesome into Quilljs editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
"::fa-camera-retro::".replace(/::(.*)::/, (string,match) => 
    `<i class="fas ${match}"></i>`
)
```

The `replace` method takes a Regular expression (`/::(.*)::/`). Here we match the two sets of colons, and anything in between is put into parentheses, making them a match group. The second argument to `replace` can be a function. The parameters are the match, and then any groups that you declare within the match. That function returns the string to replace the original whole match.

Note that this won't work for a number of matches, but you could solve that by either tweaking the regex (preferable) or by manipulating the text to manage one token at a time (slower).

[Hint](https://regex101.com/r/vYh5iv/2)